# virtualenv not being taken into account (No module name dotenv) in script

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, gunicorn

I have a script that is supposed to start gunicorn:

```
set -x
cd $VIRTUALENV
. bin/activate
pip freeze
cd $DJANGODIR

### Start Gunicorn

exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
        --name $NAME \
        --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
        --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
        --log-level=debug \
        --bind=127.0.0.1:8000
```

From the output of it, it seems pretty clear that the virtual env gets activated and the requirement is installed correctly (since the module is displayed when displaying the `pip freeze`):

```
+ cd /home/ubuntu/envs/app
+ . bin/activate
++ deactivate nondestructive
++ unset -f pydoc
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -n /bin/bash ']'
++ hash -r
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ unset VIRTUAL_ENV
++ '[' '!' nondestructive = nondestructive ']'
++ VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/ubuntu/envs/app
++ export VIRTUAL_ENV
++ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:
/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ PATH=/home/ubuntu/envs/app/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/s
bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ export PATH
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1=
++ '[' x '!=' x ']'
+++ basename /home/ubuntu/envs/app
++ PS1='(app) '
++ export PS1
++ alias pydoc
++ '[' -n /bin/bash ']'
++ hash -r
+ pip freeze
Django==2.2.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
postgres==2.2.2
psycopg2-binary==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.10.2
python-memcached==1.59
pytz==2019.1
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
+ cd /home/ubuntu/app/app

+ exec gunicorn app.wsgi:application --name app --workers 3 --user=ubuntu --group=ubuntu --log-le
vel=debug --bind=127.0.0.1:8000
...
```

Now, this script fails with the following error:

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/project/app/app/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
ImportError: No module named dotenv
```

Which lead me to suspect that the virtualenv does not remain activated...

If I do the same steps manually, I do not get the error:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/envs/app
. bin/activate
python
>>> from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
>>>
```

Any pointer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution: install gunicorn as part of the virtual environment.
Typically update the `requirements.txt` to add the following line:

```
gunicorn
```

Only using the 'gunicorn' installed with the debian package was making it from outside of the virtualenv context.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the application is not looking for packages in the right place. Try calling `sys.path.append()` to indicate where libraries are located (need to change the path accordingly to match the environment setup):

```py
import sys, os
app_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(app_root + '/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages')

# now you can import the library
from dotenv import load_dotenv
```